# jQuery not parsing JSON in PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jsonp

I'm trying to parse a JSON from a server using JSONP with jQuery.
The code below is used with PhoneGap, for creating an Android app using HTML.
When I use the code below in Safari, e.g., it works fine, but with phone gap it simply does not work!

Does anybody know the reason why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PortalARP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#conteudoArea").append("<ul></ul>");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://portalarp.com.br/portal/produto/gerar_json?id_categoria_pai=56',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonp: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrFeed',
                success: function (d) {
                    $('#title').text(d.id_produto);

                    var i, l = d.items.length, newLi, newItem;

                    $('<ul id="photoList"></ul>').appendTo('#main');

                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        newLi = $('<li></li>');
                        newItem = d.items[i];

                        $('<h2>' + newItem.nm_produto + '</h2>').appendTo(newLi);
                        $('<h3>' + newItem.nm_marca + '</h3>').appendTo(newLi);

                        newLi.appendTo('#photoList');

                    }
                }
            });
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="main"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: PS.: there are some tags name like photoList, Flick... The reason why it is like this is because I used an example I googled which was using Flick Json...

Comment: have you whitelisted the url, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Yes. I added the tag `<access origin="http://portalarp.com.br*" />` but it still doesn't show the page...

Comment: works fine on my android 2.2 with above code, can you check are there any errors in the log??

Comment: It doesn't work neither in emulator nor on device using android 2.3... In log cat, it doesn't show me any errors
I can't really figure out what's going on...

Comment: How did you specify the permission `<access origin=""` to run in 2.2 device?

Comment: The problem is with Android 2.1! I'm using sdk with android 2.1 and I tested in another computer which is using sdk with android 2.2 and it worked fine!

I will download the SDK again!

Thanks dhaval!

Comment: i will put in the answer if you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitelist the url in `res/xml/cordova.xml` and it should work.

```
<access origin="http://portalarp.com.br" />
```

For more detail check docs:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

I would check that $.support.cors and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages are both true in your setup per the [jquery mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html).